# need help to perform batching on my set of data based on subitem count in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, batching

For instance , i have a list of items

```
<list1,50>
<list2,30>
<list3,10>
<list4,70>
<list5,40>
<list6,5>
```

and maxBatchCount as 50:

Batching would result in: (One batch can have max count as 50 if possible)

```
Batch 1 : <list1,50>
Batch 2 : <list2,30>,<list3,10>,<list6,5>
Batch 3 : <list4,70>
Batch 4 : <list5,40>
```

[UPDATE]
I have written this small piece of code , which works , but still need help optimizing it further.

```
 class Items {
            public int subItemCount { get; set; }
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<Items> allItems = new LinkedList<Items>();
            allItems.AddFirst(new Items() { subItemCount = 50 });
            allItems.AddLast(new Items() { subItemCount = 30 });
            allItems.AddLast(new Items() { subItemCount = 10 });
            allItems.AddLast(new Items() { subItemCount = 70 });
            allItems.AddLast(new Items() { subItemCount = 40 });
            allItems.AddLast(new Items() { subItemCount = 5 });  
            int maxCount = 50;    
            List<List<Items>> batches = BatchItems(allItems, maxCount);
        }

private static List<List<Items>> BatchItems(LinkedList<Items> allItems, int maxCount)
        {
            List<List<Items>> allBatches = new List<List<Items>>();
            while (allItems.Where(e=>e.subItemCount<=maxCount).Count()>0)
            {
                int count = 0;
                var firstNode = allItems.First;
                while (count < maxCount && firstNode!=null)
                {
                    List<Items> batch = new List<Items>();                    
                    while(firstNode!=null)
                    {
                        if (count + firstNode.Value.subItemCount <= maxCount)
                        {
                            count += firstNode.Value.subItemCount;
                            batch.Add(firstNode.Value);
                            var deleteNode = firstNode;
                            firstNode = firstNode.Next;
                            allItems.Remove(deleteNode);

                        }
                        else
                            firstNode = firstNode.Next;
                    }
                    allBatches.Add(batch);
                } 
            }
            foreach (var item in allItems)
            {
                allBatches.Add(new List<Items>() { item });
            }
            return allBatches;

        }

This code will give me 4 Batches:
Batch 1 : List<Items>(){ {Item = 50}}
Batch 2: List<Items>(){ {Item = 30},{Item = 10},{Item = 5}}
Batch 3: List<Items>(){ {Item = 40}}
Batch 4: List<Items>(){ {Item = 70}}
```

Can this be optimized further?

Comment: To clarify: you have a `List<List<Item>>`?!

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? Any code or any problems?

Comment: Do we have to batch in *order*, e.g. can we create a batch, say `<list3, list5>` (please, notice, the abscence of `list4`)?

Comment: i have updated my code, thanks

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks , i noticed that , and have updated my question, any combination will do , as long as sum is 50 or less